# How do I pass a newly created ID from the Order Controller to the Order Item Controller in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

What I want to do is pass a newly created `OrderID` from my `Order Controller` Create Form to the `OrderItem Controller` Create Form, and add Order_Items related to that specific `OrderID` I just passed. I managed to redirect the Create Order button to take me straight to the OrderItem Index Form, but it's still pulling all the previously created `OrderIDs` including the new `OrderID` when I want to add new `OrderItems`. I want the form to only pull the `OrderID` I just created, not all the other `OrderIDs` previously created.

Also, the reason I redirected it to the Order Item Index Form was so that I could see all the Order Item's related to that specific `OrderID`, yet it still displays all the `OrderItems` created for every single `OrderID`.

I have no idea how to do this since I'm fairly new to MVC, so all help is greatly appreciated.

This is the code for the Order Controller:

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using HealthHabitat.DAL;
    using HealthHabitat.Models;

    namespace HealthHabitat.Controllers
    {
          {
            private HealthContext db = new HealthContext();

        // GET: Order
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Delivery).Include(o => o.Hospital).Include(o => o.Staff);
            return View(orders.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Order/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
            if (order == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(order);
        }

        // GET: Order/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.HospitalID = new SelectList(db.Hospitals, "HospitalID", "Name");
            ViewBag.StaffID = new SelectList(db.Staffs, "StaffID", "First_Name");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Order/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "OrderID,HospitalID,StaffID,Date,Time")] Order order)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Orders.Add(order);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index","OrderItem", new { id = "OrderID" });
            }


            ViewBag.HospitalID = new SelectList(db.Hospitals, "HospitalID", "Name", order.HospitalID);
            ViewBag.StaffID = new SelectList(db.Staffs, "StaffID", "First_Name", order.StaffID);
            return View(order);
        }

        // GET: Order/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
            if (order == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.DeliveryID = new SelectList(db.Deliverys, "DeliveryID", "DeliveryID", order.DeliveryID);
            ViewBag.HospitalID = new SelectList(db.Hospitals, "HospitalID", "Name", order.HospitalID);
            ViewBag.StaffID = new SelectList(db.Staffs, "StaffID", "First_Name", order.StaffID);
            return View(order);
        }

        // POST: Order/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "OrderID,HospitalID,StaffID,DeliveryID,Date,Time")] Order order)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.DeliveryID = new SelectList(db.Deliverys, "DeliveryID", "DeliveryID", order.DeliveryID);
            ViewBag.HospitalID = new SelectList(db.Hospitals, "HospitalID", "Name", order.HospitalID);
            ViewBag.StaffID = new SelectList(db.Staffs, "StaffID", "First_Name", order.StaffID);
            return View(order);
        }

        // GET: Order/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
            if (order == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(order);
        }

        // POST: Order/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
            db.Orders.Remove(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
    }
```

This is the code for the Order_Item Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using HealthHabitat.DAL;
using HealthHabitat.Models;

namespace HealthHabitat.Controllers
{
    public class OrderItemController : Controller
    {
        private HealthContext db = new HealthContext();

        // GET: OrderItem
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var order_Items = db.Order_Items.Include(o => o.Item).Include(o => o.Order);

            return View(order_Items.ToList());


        }

        // GET: OrderItem/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Order_Item order_Item = db.Order_Items.Find(id);
            if (order_Item == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(order_Item);
        }

        // GET: OrderItem/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemID", "Name");
            ViewBag.OrderID = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: OrderItem/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Order_ItemID,OrderID,ItemID,Type,Quantity")] Order_Item order_Item)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Order_Items.Add(order_Item);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemID", "Name", order_Item.ItemID);
            ViewBag.OrderID = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID", order_Item.OrderID);
            return View(order_Item);
        }

        // GET: OrderItem/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Order_Item order_Item = db.Order_Items.Find(id);
            if (order_Item == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemID", "Name", order_Item.ItemID);
            ViewBag.OrderID = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID", order_Item.OrderID);
            return View(order_Item);
        }

        // POST: OrderItem/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Order_ItemID,OrderID,ItemID,Type,Quantity")] Order_Item order_Item)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(order_Item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemID", "Name", order_Item.ItemID);
            ViewBag.OrderID = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID", order_Item.OrderID);
            return View(order_Item);
        }

        // GET: OrderItem/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Order_Item order_Item = db.Order_Items.Find(id);
            if (order_Item == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(order_Item);
        }

        // POST: OrderItem/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Order_Item order_Item = db.Order_Items.Find(id);
            db.Order_Items.Remove(order_Item);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Order Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace HealthHabitat.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Hospital")]
        public int HospitalID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Staff")]
        public int StaffID { get; set; }
        public int? DeliveryID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:H:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }

        public virtual Hospital Hospital { get; set; }
        public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }
        public virtual Delivery Delivery { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

OrderItem Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace HealthHabitat.Models
{
    public class OrderItem
    {

        public int OrderItemID { get; set; }
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public int ItemID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Item Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace HealthHabitat.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Item Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Item Name")]

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Item Quantity")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-mm-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Expiry Date")]
        public DateTime Expiry_Date { get; set; }
        public int Consumption { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little unclear of what the purpose of your `Index()` method in `OrderItemController` would be. Your just displaying all order items for all orders. Typically your `Details()` method for `OrderController` would display details of the order and a list of items associated with that order (perhaps as a table showing all details of each OrderItem in cluding links to edit/delete, or as links to the `Details()` method of `OrderItemController` if there is too much information to display on the one page)

I would suggest the following structure

OrderController

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  // Display a collection on all orders
}
public ActionResult Details(int ID)
{
  // Display the details of an order, including a collection of its order items
}
public ActionResult Create()
{
  // Create a new Order
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Order model)
{
  // Save the order
  return RedirectToAction("Details", new { ID = model.ID });
}
```

The `Details.cshtml` view would then include a link (menu item) to create a new `OrderItem` associated with the `Order`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Item", "Create", "OrderItem", new { ID = Model.OrderID }, null)
```

OrderItemController

```
public ActionResult Create(int ID) // ID is the ID of the Order
{
  OrderItem model = new OrderItem() { OrderID = ID };
  return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(OrderItem model)
{
  // Save the OrderItem and redirect to the order details page
  return RedirectToAction("Details", "Order", new { ID = model.OrderID });
}
```

In the `Create.cshtml` view for `OrderDetails`, include the `OrderID` as a route value in the form, or include a hidden input inside the form

```
@model OrderDetail
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { OrderID = Model.OrderID }))
{
  ....
}
```

Side note: Recommend you follow normal naming conventions - `OrderItem`, not `Order_Item` - and use view models, especially for creating/editing and remove those awful `[Bind(Include = "...")]` attributes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely take those naming conventions into account. Could please elaborate further on how I would include the display of a collection of order items in my Order Controller details method?

Comment: The `Details(int ID)` method would have something like (cant be sure without seeing the models) `db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == ID).Include("OrderItems").FirstOrDefault();` - you may not need the `.Include()` depending on how you have set up EF. Then in the view `foreach (var item in Model.OrderItems) { ... }`

Comment: I've included the models just in case it might make a difference to your reply. Thanks again.

Comment: What I showed in my last comment should work fine - `Order` contains a property `OrderItems` which is a collection of `OrderItem`

Comment: The foreach (var item in Model.OrderItems) {...} line, where would I put it in my details.cshtml? Would I put it on a separate row?

Comment: We are getting a bit off track here, and I have no idea what you want to display relating to each order item (for example, just a link to a page showing the details of the `OrderItem` or a table showing all properties of each `OrderItem`?) It really depends on what you want to display. If `OrderItem` only contains a few properties, I would suggest a table, one row for each `OrderItem` with perhaps additional columns for and 'edit' and 'delete' link.

Comment: Foe example `foreach(var item in Model.OrderItems) { <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.SomeProperty)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.AnotherProperty)</td><td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "OrderItem", new { ID = item.ID })</td></tr> }`

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for all your help. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` parameter to your `Index` action in your `OrderItemController` and use that id to filter the order items.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{

    var order_Items = db.Order_Items.Include(o => o.Item).Include(o => o.Order).Where(o => o.OrderId == id);

    return View(order_Items.ToList());
}
```